# Generate timestamp by minutes and calculate sum of uniques by every minutes

Tags: json, bash, timestamp, jq

I have an ndjson like this

```
{"start_time_last":"2019-02-24T00:07:25.875Z","start_time_first":"2019-02-24T00:07:25.875Z","device_id":"8160a3f87a977379f12f8826fd3c9c86ca3ca48a"}
{"start_time_last":"2019-02-24T00:48:56.100Z","start_time_first":"2019-02-24T00:40:24.464Z","device_id":"181606aabbf155217f59e302541638bfc7e07837"}
{"start_time_last":"2019-02-23T21:57:36.024Z","start_time_first":"2019-02-23T21:56:06.741Z","device_id":"1b62573cdfdab3902b72ec9e4797c422271f2efd"}
```

As you see each record shows an active period of a device, my question is if I want to generate a ndjson, which have two fields. One is "timestamp" which go through 2019-02-23T00:00, 2019-02-23T00:01, ..., 2019-02-24T23:59 (timestamps by minutes) and count the uniques of distinct device_id that is active by every timestamps.

For example, for the first record, it starts from 2019-02-24T00:07:25.875Z and end at 2019-02-24T00:07:25.875Z. This device id should be counted in timestamps:

```
2019-02-24T00:07
```

As it only appears in this minute. For second record, it should be counted in these timestamps

```
2019-02-24T00:40,
2019-02-24T00:41,
2019-02-24T00:42,
2019-02-24T00:43,
2019-02-24T00:44,
2019-02-24T00:45,
2019-02-24T00:46,
2019-02-24T00:47,
2019-02-24T00:48
```

How to realize this using jq? Or whatever command in Bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you want (for each "minute") a count of the number of active devices. Here is a solution that assumes that the input specifies non-overlapping intervals for each "device_id":

```
def seconds:
    # strips fractional seconds
    "\(.[:-5])Z" | fromdateiso8601;

def record($s; $e):
  reduce range($s | round; $e + 1) as $i (.; .[$i|todate] += 1);

reduce inputs as $in ({}; record( ($in | .start_time_first | seconds / 60); ($in | .start_time_last | seconds / 60)))
```

## Invocation

An appropriate invocation would look like this:

```
jq -n -f program.jq input.ndjson
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you're taking those objects as inputs and generating a series of objects with a `timestamp` within the range of `start_time_*` dates for every minute and the `device_id`.

If your OS and build supports date functions, you could use this to generate your json.

```
def fromdateiso8601wd:
    # strips fractional seconds
    "\(.[:-5])Z" | fromdateiso8601;
[
    (.start_time_first | fromdateiso8601wd),
    (.start_time_last  | fromdateiso8601wd + 60)
] as [$s, $e] |
{
    timestamp: (range($s; $e; 60) | todateiso8601),
    device_id
}
```

Would produce:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2019-02-24T00:07:25Z",
  "device_id": "8160a3f87a977379f12f8826fd3c9c86ca3ca48a"
}
{
  "timestamp": "2019-02-24T00:40:24Z",
  "device_id": "181606aabbf155217f59e302541638bfc7e07837"
}
{
  "timestamp": "2019-02-24T00:41:24Z",
  "device_id": "181606aabbf155217f59e302541638bfc7e07837"
}
{
  "timestamp": "2019-02-24T00:42:24Z",
  "device_id": "181606aabbf155217f59e302541638bfc7e07837"
}
{
  "timestamp": "2019-02-24T00:43:24Z",
  "device_id": "181606aabbf155217f59e302541638bfc7e07837"
}
{
  "timestamp": "2019-02-24T00:44:24Z",
  "device_id": "181606aabbf155217f59e302541638bfc7e07837"
}
{
  "timestamp": "2019-02-24T00:45:24Z",
  "device_id": "181606aabbf155217f59e302541638bfc7e07837"
}
{
  "timestamp": "2019-02-24T00:46:24Z",
  "device_id": "181606aabbf155217f59e302541638bfc7e07837"
}
{
  "timestamp": "2019-02-24T00:47:24Z",
  "device_id": "181606aabbf155217f59e302541638bfc7e07837"
}
{
  "timestamp": "2019-02-24T00:48:24Z",
  "device_id": "181606aabbf155217f59e302541638bfc7e07837"
}
{
  "timestamp": "2019-02-24T00:49:24Z",
  "device_id": "181606aabbf155217f59e302541638bfc7e07837"
}
{
  "timestamp": "2019-02-23T21:56:06Z",
  "device_id": "1b62573cdfdab3902b72ec9e4797c422271f2efd"
}
{
  "timestamp": "2019-02-23T21:57:06Z",
  "device_id": "1b62573cdfdab3902b72ec9e4797c422271f2efd"
}
{
  "timestamp": "2019-02-23T21:58:06Z",
  "device_id": "1b62573cdfdab3902b72ec9e4797c422271f2efd"
}
```

Comment: Hi Jeff, Thank you. This seems exactly the solution I am looking for. But would you mind post a command on how to apply this 'fromdateiso8601wd' function to a .ndjson file? Using foreach for each line or I just pass the whole .ndjson file? Thank you!

Comment: What I had typed out here is the filter you would use in `jq`. Though since it is written out as multiline, it might be a little awkward (especially on Windows). You can rewrite as a single line as well but for readability, I wouldn't recommend. Instead, you could put the contents in a file -- say `program.jq` -- then pass that file in using the `-f` option. Then you would invoke it as `jq -f program.jq input.ndjson`